# extract dictionary from Counter object

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I want to count the number of times a word occur in a list of sting.

```
['this is a red ball','this is another red ball']
```

I wrote the following code

```
counts = Counter()
for sentence in lines:
    counts.update(word.strip('.,?!"\'').lower() for word in sentence.split())
```

It gives me a result in the following format

```
Counter({'': 6, 'red': 2, 'this': 2, ....})
```

How can I only get the dictionary?

Comment: A `Counter` is a subclass of a dictionary - everything you can do with the former, you can do with the latter. Why do you want to convert it to a vanilla dict? But it's easy enough: `dict(counts)`.

Answer (score 23):

You can just do the following if a dictionary is really what you want.

```
dict(counts)
```

Though you will have all the operations in `counts` variable which you can do in a normal python dictionary because `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`.

From [`Counter` docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

> A [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a **[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) subclass** for counting hashable objects.

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 6):

A Counter is simply a dict subclass. There is no need to "get" the dictionary; it *is* a dictionary, and supports all the dict operators and methods (although `update` works slightly differently).

If for some reason the fact that it reports itself to be a Counter rather than a dict *really* bothers you, you could just do `counts = dict(counts)` to convert it back to the superclass. But there's no need to do that.